# Finding matrix with respect to basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P^2$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree ≤ 2. A function $T : P^2 → \mathbf{R^2}$ is deﬁned by $T(p(x)) = (p(1),p(2))$.

a) Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard bases $B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ for $P^2$ and $S = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ for $\mathbf{R^2}$.

b) Find bases for the kernel and the image of $T$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Plug in your basis vectors, $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$. Write them as coordinate vectors in $S$. Then put them into columns in the order specified.

Answer (score 0):

1. See $ P^2 $ is isomorphic to $R^3$. this solves your entire Problem.
2. 1=(1,0,0), x=(0,1,0) and $x^2$ =(0,0,1).

3.Now the rest of the problem is easy.

if you want further explanation and details.please be free to tell!!